# Having trouble moving files from raspi to git local repo

Tags: git, raspberry-pi

I cloned git repo to raspi, to which I am connected remotely. Trying to move file from outside folder to that git repository. 
Tried and failed with:

```
git mv [sourse] [destination]
```

Can anyone help please to move files from my raspi to that git repository folder or maybe somehow push the files to remote repository without necessarily moving that to local git repo?
To do the second, I tried and failed with:
 https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move the files with `mv source destination` and then use `git add file`, `git commit`, `git push`?

Comment: thanks for response! For some reason, when I do mv source destination, the file does not appear in the destination

Comment: Can you do it outside of the console? Do you have access permissions to that file?

Comment: yes, actually, the command is executed without error. It is just that I don't see the file itself in destination

Comment: And if you do `git status` does it appear?

Comment: no, but the file disappears from source folder so it goes somewhere